# Reading JSON code and Write to mysql

Tags: php, sql, json

i have small problem i have to read "title" and "coordinates" from here https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp

And save them in my database like this:

[image: valid HTML]

I made this php script but its not working properly:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
$filePath = "link here";
$tableName = "test";
$fieldDelimiter = '"coordinates":[-""';
$lineDelimiter = "\n";
mysqli_query($con, '
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$filePath.'"
    INTO TABLE '.$tableName.'
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \'' . $fieldDelimiter . '\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'' . $lineDelimiter . '\'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
') or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows FROM " . $tableName);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$total_rows = $result['total_rows'];
echo $total_rows . " rows have been added to the table " . $tableName;
?>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: what exactly is not working here? It's better if you could explain what's the problem you are facing

Comment: I want to take some name and the cordinates from the link  and write them in my db like the pic that i have uploaded

Comment: The link to the file you posted is not a valid json. Have you noticed `eqfeed_callback(` at the beginning of your file which messes up the JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

Make double quote sign " outside and single quote sign inside here $fieldDelimiter = '"coordinates":[-""';

Comment: The script does not work when i write it like that. :D

Comment: You have lot of single and double quote. Make it consistently everywhere double outside and single inside.

Comment: This is all after $con, in single quote, make it double quote:

mysqli_query($con, '
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$filePath.'"
    INTO TABLE '.$tableName.'
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \'' . $fieldDelimiter . '\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'' . $lineDelimiter . '\'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
')